# How can I calculate a forloop that will update my column vector without replacing the current value?

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm working on a for-loop to calculate post-error slowing. Basically, if a participant gets a trial incorrect (`key_resp_corr = 0`), I want to see if they slow down on the next trial (ie. the key_resp.rt from the next trial minus the key_resp.rt from the current trial.

Here's some code for some example data (called MixedRSI):

```
structure(list(X = 25:35, display = c("HHHHH", "HHHHH", "HHHHH", 
"SSSSS", "HHSHH", "SSSSS", "HHHHH", "SSHSS", "SSSSS", "HHHHH", 
"SSSSS"), correctAns = c("z", "z", "z", "slash", "slash", "slash", 
"z", "z", "slash", "z", "slash"), RSI = c(0.6, 1.4, 1.3, 0.8, 
0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.6, 0.8, 1.2, 0.6), key = c("z", "z", "z", "slash", 
"z", "slash", "z", "z", "slash", "z", "slash"), key_resp_corr = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), key_resp.rt = c(0.796000004, 
1.430000067, 1.462999821, 0.946999788, 0.881000042, 1.263999939, 
1.113000154, 0.812999964, 0.897000074, 1.364000082, 0.697000027
), Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Block = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Condition = c("Mixed", 
"Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", 
"Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed"), PES = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0)), row.names = 25:35, class = "data.frame")
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
ntrials <- (nrow(MixedRSI)-1)
MixedRSI$PES <- 0
for (i in ntrials) {
    MixedRSI$PES[i] <-
      ifelse(
          MixedRSI$key_resp_corr[i] == 0,
          yes = (MixedRSI$key_resp.rt[i+1] - MixedRSI$key_resp.rt[i]),
          no  =  MixedRSI$PES[i])
}
```

The issue is that it does not update the PES column with the correct value when it should- it just leaves it at zero. I'm confused because when I run the ifelse statement on its own when `i = 4`, it appears to work perfectly. Is there something I'm missing here? Is it somehow overriding my entry when `i = 4`?

Comment: It is a good idea to make your question reproducible, so providing a minimal set of data (e.g. use `dput(mydata)` to output your data in a format easy to cut/paste) and code that uses that minimal set of data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You should not use `ifelse` on single conditionals: while it still works somewhat like the more canonical `if (..) {..} else {..}`, the ifelse function has some well known issues (none impacted here). Typically, when I see an `ifelse` within a `for` loop, the for loop can be removed and use *just* the `ifelse` function.

Comment: @steveb updated with this information

Comment: @r2evans I think I may be a bit confused- when I remove the for loop, the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go without loops:

```
check <- df$key_resp_corr == 0
diffs <- diff(df$key_resp.rt)
diffs <- c(diffs, 0)
newPES <- check * diffs
newPES <- ifelse(newPES > 0, 1, 0)
df$PES <- newPES
df
    X display correctAns RSI   key key_resp_corr key_resp.rt Subject Block Condition PES
25 25   HHHHH          z 0.6     z             1   0.7960000       1     1     Mixed   0
26 26   HHHHH          z 1.4     z             1   1.4300001       1     1     Mixed   0
27 27   HHHHH          z 1.3     z             1   1.4629998       1     1     Mixed   0
28 28   SSSSS      slash 0.8 slash             1   0.9469998       1     1     Mixed   0
29 29   HHSHH      slash 0.7     z             0   0.8810000       1     1     Mixed   1
30 30   SSSSS      slash 0.8 slash             1   1.2639999       1     1     Mixed   0
31 31   HHHHH          z 0.8     z             1   1.1130002       1     1     Mixed   0
32 32   SSHSS          z 0.6     z             1   0.8130000       1     1     Mixed   0
33 33   SSSSS      slash 0.8 slash             1   0.8970001       1     1     Mixed   0
34 34   HHHHH          z 1.2     z             1   1.3640001       1     1     Mixed   0
35 35   SSSSS      slash 0.6 slash             1   0.6970000       1     1     Mixed   0
```

RSVP if that's not what you want.  Or please uptick and check answered.

Comment: Thanks @SteveM ! with a few modifications I was able to make this work.

Comment: Here's what I used ```MixedRSI$NewCorr <- recode(MixedRSI$key_resp_corr, "1" = "0", "0" = "1")
MixedRSI$NewCorr <-as.numeric(MixedRSI$NewCorr)
diffs <- diff(MixedRSI$key_resp.rt)
diffs <- c(diffs, 0)
newPES <- MixedRSI$NewCorr * diffs
MixedRSI$PES <- newPES```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```r
MixedRSI <- structure(list(X = 25:35, 
                           display = c("HHHHH", "HHHHH", "HHHHH", 
                           "SSSSS", "HHSHH", "SSSSS", "HHHHH", "SSHSS", "SSSSS", "HHHHH", 
                           "SSSSS"), correctAns = c("z", "z", "z", "slash", "slash", "slash", 
                         "z", "z", "slash", "z", "slash"), RSI = c(0.6, 1.4, 1.3, 0.8, 
                          0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.6, 0.8, 1.2, 0.6), key = c("z", "z", "z", "slash", 
                          "z", "slash", "z", "z", "slash", "z", "slash"), key_resp_corr = c(1L, 
                          1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), key_resp.rt = c(0.796000004, 
                         1.430000067, 1.462999821, 0.946999788, 0.881000042, 1.263999939, 
                         1.113000154, 0.812999964, 0.897000074, 1.364000082, 0.697000027), 
                         Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Block = c(1L, 
                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Condition = c("Mixed", 
                         "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", 
                         "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed"), PES = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                             0, 0)), row.names = 25:35, class = "data.frame")

#dplyr solution
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

MixedRSI %>% 
  mutate(PES = case_when(
    key_resp_corr == 0 ~ lag(key_resp.rt) - key_resp.rt,
    T ~ 0
  ))
#>     X display correctAns RSI   key key_resp_corr key_resp.rt Subject Block
#> 1  25   HHHHH          z 0.6     z             1   0.7960000       1     1
#> 2  26   HHHHH          z 1.4     z             1   1.4300001       1     1
#> 3  27   HHHHH          z 1.3     z             1   1.4629998       1     1
#> 4  28   SSSSS      slash 0.8 slash             1   0.9469998       1     1
#> 5  29   HHSHH      slash 0.7     z             0   0.8810000       1     1
#> 6  30   SSSSS      slash 0.8 slash             1   1.2639999       1     1
#> 7  31   HHHHH          z 0.8     z             1   1.1130002       1     1
#> 8  32   SSHSS          z 0.6     z             1   0.8130000       1     1
#> 9  33   SSSSS      slash 0.8 slash             1   0.8970001       1     1
#> 10 34   HHHHH          z 1.2     z             1   1.3640001       1     1
#> 11 35   SSSSS      slash 0.6 slash             1   0.6970000       1     1
#>    Condition        PES
#> 1      Mixed 0.00000000
#> 2      Mixed 0.00000000
#> 3      Mixed 0.00000000
#> 4      Mixed 0.00000000
#> 5      Mixed 0.06599975
#> 6      Mixed 0.00000000
#> 7      Mixed 0.00000000
#> 8      Mixed 0.00000000
#> 9      Mixed 0.00000000
#> 10     Mixed 0.00000000
#> 11     Mixed 0.00000000
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>